# Swift - Return string between two NSRanges

Tags: html, regex, xml, xcode, swift

I have a function that returns the NSRange of all `<h1>` (and `</h1>`) tags in an XML document. How can I use regex to get the string between each instance of `<h1>` and `</h1>` tags using these NSRanges? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Parser are efficient than using regex while working on `XML` and `HTML` content.

Comment: I have already used an XML parser to get a bunch of html code out of a CDATA tag and place it into one big string.

Comment: I have made a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR3yF1/1). Is this what you want to do ? If not then please clarify your question and also add some valid and invalid cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer here...

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-string-cheat-sheet/

To identify a range of elements in a String collection use a range. A range is just a start and end index:

```
let fqdn = "useyourloaf.com"
let rangeOfTLD = Range(start: fqdn.endIndex.advancedBy(-3), 
                     end: fqdn.endIndex)
let tld = fqdn[rangeOfTLD] // "com"
```

Alternate creation of range using the “…” or “..<” operators:

```
let rangeOfDomain = fqdn.startIndex..<fqdn.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
let domain = fqdn[rangeOfDomain] // "useyourloaf"
```